# passing html value from a form to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass the value and text from a form to a JavaScript function using the onclick on a button but don't seem to be able to get it to work I want to keep this as generic as possible so I copy and paste the form

```
    <form name='f1'>
    <form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Span>
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="68">


 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
 <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@hotmail.com">
 <select name="del">
 <option value="0">Delivery To</option>
 <option value="41">Uk</option>
 <option value="39">USA</option>
 <option value="20">World Wide</option>
</select>

      <input type="image" src="http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but22.gif"   
onClick="shipping1(this.options.selectedindex.value,this.options.selectedindex.text)" border="0" name="submit" width="87" height="23"        alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
   </form>
   </form>
```

i think it may be the formating of this.options
any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
onClick="shipping1(this.form.del[this.form.del.selectedIndex].value,this.form.del[this.form.del.selectedIndex].text)"
```